# How we can restrict Wi-Fi to access internet to any application?

Tags: android, wifi, android-source, wifimanager

I want to connect with wifi after connection which does not provide internet to any application.

How to restrict wifi internet access to any applicaton ?
Any suggestions let me know please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you set a  dynamic network address within a program and utilize the website blocker to block the programs access to  network it's network.